# Do zend framework has application setup wizard module?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm looking at zend framework 2 to use it for my project.

Wanted to know if it has an in-build php web application installer script/module like mentioned in this thread [How I can create installer for website. PHP mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388513/how-i-can-create-installer-for-website-php-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

I would say using [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) with your own `composer.json` is as close as you can get...

As an example there is the [`ZF2 Skeleton Application`](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication). Similarly you can also make a `composer.json` for your own custom application pointing to your custom repository and all dependencies.