# Installer and updater for php web application

Tags: php, yii2

I'm making a web app in yii2 and I'm thinking about releasing it with an installer similar to wp where you can setup your db and create the first user.
In the future I would like to push updates to the instances too and I'm not sure if I should use git for this or something else.
 
Does anyone have any experience with this or tips where should I start searching?

Answer (score 0):

I will start adding links that I found

Installers
[How I can create installer for website. PHP mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388513/how-i-can-create-installer-for-website-php-mysql)

I think I will just create the installer myself that will call composer install and yii migrate and create a file with the db configuration.

I think the update could be a bit more complicated but this project looks good. 
https://github.com/VisualAppeal/PHP-Auto-Update
I would still prefer a git solution but I'm not sure if that's even possible.